# How to apply conditions to str.split()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains a string of varying length in each cell i.e.

```
    Num
(1,2,3,4,5)
(6,7,8)
(9)
(10,11,12)
```

I want to avoid attempting to perform str.split(',') on the cells that only have one number in them. However, I want all of the single numbers to be converted to a list of one element.

Here is what I have tried, it gives an error that says " 'int' object is not callable"

```
if(df['Num'].size() > 1):
    df['Num'] = df['Num'].str.split(',')
```

update for clarification:

```
Index      Num
0          2,6,7
1      1,3,6,7,8
2      2,4,7,8,9
3     3,5,8,9,10
4         4,9,10
5          1,2,7
6      1,2,3,6,8
7      2,3,4,7,9
8     3,4,5,8,10
9          4,5,9
10           2,3
11           1,3
12           1,2
13         2,3,4
14         1,3,4
15         1,2,4
16         1,2,3
17             2
18             1
```

I am trying to take this dataframe and convert each Num row from a string of numbers to a list. I want all of the indices that contain only one number (17 and 18) to be converted to a list containing a single element (itself).

This code below only works if every string is more than one number separated by a ','.

```
df['Adj'] = df['Adj'].str.split(',')
```

The output dataframe that I get when I run the above code. Notice the elements that only had one number are now nan.

```
Index          Num
0            [2, 6, 7]
1      [1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
2      [2, 4, 7, 8, 9]
3     [3, 5, 8, 9, 10]
4           [4, 9, 10]
5            [1, 2, 7]
6      [1, 2, 3, 6, 8]
7      [2, 3, 4, 7, 9]
8     [3, 4, 5, 8, 10]
9            [4, 5, 9]
10              [2, 3]
11              [1, 3]
12              [1, 2]
13           [2, 3, 4]
14           [1, 3, 4]
15           [1, 2, 4]
16           [1, 2, 3]
17                 NaN
18                 NaN
```

Comment: Are these strings or tuples, e.g. what do you see for `type(df['Num'].iat[0])` and `type(df['Num'].iat[2])`?

Comment: str.split splits a string using a given delimiter (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html). The type of each cell is not a string, that's why you get this error!

Comment: You should do `df[ df['Num'].size > 1 ]['Num'].str.split(',')` I think. But there might be more to the question you're asking. You should write a proper question with a [mcve].

Comment: `df['Num'].size` is a property, not a method.  `df['Num'].size()` is where the error occurs.

Comment: Why not just `df['Num'].str.split(',')` though? You wanted `(9)` to not be in a `list` like the rest of the column? It's not like splitting `(9)` will cause any issue... it just won't split.  Also `size` is not what you think it is...

Comment: Sorry let me clarify a little bit. I want the single numbers to be converted to a list of one element, and everything else to be converted to a list of, well, multiple elements .

Comment: @jpp I have updated the question, and yes they are for sure strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your column are all strings and you just want the individual numbers as a `list` of `str`, this should do the trick:

```
df['Num'].str.strip('()').str.split(',')

# 0    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# 1          [6, 7, 8]
# 2                [9]
# 3       [10, 11, 12]
# Name: Num, dtype: object
```

Since not all your data are `str` type, you'll need to coerce them into `str` first to ensure the string methods are called properly:

```
df['Num'].astype(str).str.split(',')

# 0            [2, 6, 7]
# 1      [1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
# 2      [2, 4, 7, 8, 9]
# ...
# 16           [1, 2, 3]
# 17                 [2]
# 18                 [1]
```

Comment: I posted an update to better explain, unfortunately your example wasn't exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: In your edit you said *`df['Adj'].str.split(',')` only works if every string is more than one number separated by a `','`*, but that is not the case as you can see in my answer.  If the string doesn't have any `','` it simply creates a `list` of one element.  Have you tried it? What results are you getting? Showing us the input and output would help.

Comment: Your original data are not all `str` as suspected.  Your last two items are probably `int`, that's why it returns `NaN` instead.  See my updated answer.

Comment: You're a fricken wizard harry (Idlehands). Can't believe I was overlooking those ints..